# Infinite sum of powers of the prime zeta function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

denote by $\zeta_{p}(s)$ the [Prime Zeta Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function). Now, consider the infinite sum:
$$D(s)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\zeta_{p}(s)^{n}=\frac{1}{1-\zeta_{p}(s)}\;\;\;\left | \zeta_{p}(s)\right|<1$$
$D(s)$ could be thought of as a Dirichlet series in some half plane of convergence :
$$D(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{n^{s}}$$ 
Using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, we can prove that:
$$a_{n}\neq 0,\forall n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$$
Now, I'm having a hard time making sense of the coefficients $a_{n}$. In particular, they seem to bear some interesting arithmetical information with respect to the factorization of their corresponding indices. I have the feeling that I'm missing something basic !!

Any insights on the numbers $a_{n}$ are appreciated.

Comment: I think that if $n$ can be written as a product of primes $n = p_1 \ldots p_r$ (here the primes factors are not necessarily distincts), then $a_n = r!$ (only $\zeta_p(s)^r$ contributes to the $n^{-s}$ term, and it contributes for $1$ for each permutation of the $p_i$).

Comment: @JoelCohen let me get this straight. you're saying that if $n$ is given by $n=\prod_{i}p_{i}^{b_{i}}$, then $a_{n}=\left(\sum_{i}b_{i}\right)!$, is that right !?

Comment: I think so, yes. My reasoning is in the comment above, but I might wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $P(s)$ for the [prime zeta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeZetaFunction.html). By the [multinomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem),

$$D(s)=\sum_{r=0}^\infty P(s)^r=1+\sum_{r=1}^\infty\sum_{e_{\large i}}\sum_{p_{\large i}~\mathrm{dstct}}{r\choose e_1,\cdots,e_r}\frac{1}{(p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_r^{e_r})^s}.$$

So the [Dirichlet coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series) of $D(s)$ are given by [multinomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_to_multinomials) in [$p$-adic orders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order):

$$a_n={\displaystyle\sum_p v_p(n)\choose v_2(n),v_3(n),v_5(n),\cdots}.$$

(This expression makes sense because only finitely many $v_p(n)$ are nonzero for any natural $n$.)